# Which Wi-Fi network has my HomePod mini?

Tags: homepod

How can I verify the WiFi network being used by my HomePod mini? And, how can I resign the HomePod mini to use a different WiFi?

I used the *Home* app provided by Apple on my iPhone. I long-pressed the icon for the HomePod mini. I see many settings. But I do not see anything about its current network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the HomePod settings and scroll down to "Wi-Fi Address" (in the section directly above "Reset HomePod...") Tap on "Wi-Fi Address" and it will switch to "Wi-Fi Network" and show you the network name.

If you have a Stereo Pair you have to click into "Speakers" and choose the specific device you want to examine first.